# Serialization using Boost.Serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, vector, boost-serialization

I have been trying serialization but every time I got stuck with errors like:-

```
error: 'class std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' has no member named 'serialize'
```

here is my source code and serialize method ,knowing I am use boost.serialize

```
template <class E, class T>
class heap{

    vector<E> * hp;
    int index;//index is pointing to first empty place after the last element
    int maxsize;

    T comp;//comparable object designed to compare the objects

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    // When the class Archive corresponds to an output archive, the
    // & operator is defined similar to <<.  Likewise, when the class Archive
    // is a type of input archive the & operator is defined similar to >>.
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {

        ar & hp;
        ar & index;
        ar & maxsize;
        ar & comp;
    }

public:
    //default empty constructor
    heap(){

        hp = new vector<E>(MAX);
        index = 0;
        maxsize = MAX;


    }
.
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

then i changed this line  ar & hp; into

```
for(int i = 0; i < hp->size(); i++)
   ar & hp->at(i);
```

I got even worse errors like

```
/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:100: undefined reference to `boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)'
debug/main.o: In function `~text_oarchive_impl':

Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:85: undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::ostream>::~basic_text_oprimitive()'

Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:85: undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::ostream>::~basic_text_oprimitive()'
```

Answer (score 19):

1. Include `<boost/serialization/vector.hpp>`.
2. Don't allocate `vector` dynamically.
3. Don't forget to *link* to Serialization, it's not header-only library.

Comment: Number 2 should be in big fat letters.