# Compile error on serializing boost::unordered_set

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization, unordered-set

First of all, Does boost::serialization support unordered_set now? I didn't find the header boost/serialization/unordered_set.hpp.

Here is the code I tried to implement:

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization{

template<class Archive, typename T, typename H, typename P, typename A>
void save(Archive &ar,
          const unordered::unordered_set<T,H,P,A> &s, const unsigned int) {
    vector<T> vec(s.begin(),s.end());   
    ar<<vec;    
}
template<class Archive, typename T, typename H, typename P, typename A>
void load(Archive &ar,
          unordered::unordered_set<T,H,P,A> &s, const unsigned int) {
    vector<T> vec;  
    ar>>vec;   
    std::copy(vec.begin(),vec.end(),    
              std::inserter(s,s.begin()));  
}

template<class Archive, typename T, typename H, typename P, typename A>
void serialize(Archive &ar,
               unordered::unordered_set<T,H,P,A> &s, const unsigned int version) {
    boost::serialization::split_free(ar,s,version);
}

}
}
```

Here is the error:

```
'class std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' has no member named 'serialize'
```

Plus, I still got a warning on the following code:

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive(ss)<<s1; 

Warning:comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

I'm not sure whether it's Ok to neglect it.

Comment: did you try with `boost/serialization/hash_set.hpp`?

Comment: @rhalbersma I tried and got many errors. 'In member function 'void boost::serialization::stl::archive_input_hash_set<Archive, Container>::operator()(Archive&, Container&, unsigned int)':'--'stack_construct' is not a member of 'boost::serialization::detail' and so on.

Comment: I solved the problem by including <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>   
Thanks to [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9437157/957121

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, there is no serialization support form the boost library for serializing boost.unordered containers.

http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/talkview13/items/2.html